# Ghost Imaging with a deployment server

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, ghost

I have a server to tinker with and I figure it can be used as a deployment server; as I have multiple pcs at home which don't have ghost software.

My question is - Does anyone know the best ghost deployment for a server to client? Also this software would have to be free or cheap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) sounds like it would serve you well.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. However not sure I like the look of the server - Looks linux based. However I have virtual machines running so who knows. Thanks!

Comment: It is, in fact, very Linux based.

Answer (score 1):

The [FOG Project](http://www.fogproject.org/?q=node/1) would also serve you well....

Comment: Please expand this link. Link only answers may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT) with the Windows Automated Tool Kit (WAIK) are both free and work very well with Windows Deployment Services (WDS). It builds, captures, and deploys Windows with good results. Like all MS products, there is a learning curve, but this website has some great videos on how to get started.

http://www.deploymentresearch.com/Videos/MDT2010LiteTouchUnleashedVideos.aspx